# Is there a way to speed up looping in python

Tags: python, loops, optimization, numba

I have a set of players (`common_opps`), the size of which changes over time, I need to count values from 3d dataframe (`df_versus`) and then return the mean. I am repeating this function many times and the execution time raises every time. It is Ok for small amount of players, but it comes to the moment when this loop is iterating by over 500 players and the waiting time is very long. So I was wondering if there is a way to improve this, by changing this loop to something else like lambda functions or something. I tried Numba, but can't configure it properly.

```py
def common_opponents(p1, p2):
    
    common_opps = np.array(s_opponents[p1].intersection(s_opponents[p2]))
    serve1, serve2, ace1, ace2, df1, df2, break1, break2 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

    length = len(common_opps)
    if length == 0:
        return serve1, serve2, ace1, ace2, df1, df2, break1, break2
    
    for opponent in common_opps:

        serve1 += df_versus[p1][opponent]["serve_won"] / df_versus[p1][opponent]["serve_total"]
        serve2 += df_versus[p2][opponent]["serve_won"] / df_versus[p2][opponent]["serve_total"]

        ace1 += df_versus[p1][opponent]["ace"] / df_versus[p1][opponent]["serve_total"]
        ace2 += df_versus[p2][opponent]["ace"] / df_versus[p2][opponent]["serve_total"]

        df1 += df_versus[p1][opponent]["df"] / df_versus[p1][opponent]["serve_total"]
        df2 += df_versus[p2][opponent]["df"] / df_versus[p2][opponent]["serve_total"]

        break1 += df_versus[p1][opponent]["break_won"] / df_versus[p1][opponent]["break_total"]
        break2 += df_versus[p2][opponent]["break_won"] / df_versus[p2][opponent]["break_total"]
        
    return (serve1/length, serve2/length, ace1/length, ace2/length, 
            df1/length, df2/length, break1/length, break2/length)
```

(`p1`) and (`p2`) are names of the players in string like 'Roger Federer' and 'Rafael Nadal', (`s_opponents1`) and (`s_opponents2`) are sets with players names, (`common_opps`) is also a set with names, (`df_versus`) is a multiindex data frame made with

```
versus_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([unique_player, ["serve_won", "serve_total", "ace", "df", "break_won", "break_total", "won", "lost"]]) 


df_versus = pd.DataFrame(0, index=versus_index, columns=unique_player)
```

it is filled over time with proper values and unique_players is a list of unique players in whole dataset

If Nadal and Federer would have only those 3 players I would consider that dataframe, of course the zeros should be replaced by their stats[image: data frame of common opponents]

Comment: By "data frame" do you mean that you are using pandas and numpy? If so, you should learn about broadcasting. You can use this to allow numpy to do the looping for you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes I mean pandas, but I do not understand how can I allow looping to numpy, can you give me some example?

Comment: Numba does not support Pandas yet. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so we can help you further? If no, can you at least precise the *exact* types of all input variables (eg. `p1`, `p2`, columns of `s_opponents`/`df_versus`, etc.)?

Comment: @Pleban Please [edit] your question to include these details.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out how to solve this optimization problem

Instead of this for loop I added 4 new columns to the df_versus (`['serve_ratio', 'ace_ratio', 'df_ratio', 'break_ratio']`) than I used `.apply` method to apply `np.mean` that is super fast and return it as arrays. I think that now this process is about 100 times faster

```
serve1, ace1, df1, break1, serve2, ace2, df2, break2  = (
    df_versus.loc[([p1, p2], ['serve_ratio', 'ace_ratio', 'df_ratio', 'break_ratio']),
                  common_opps].apply(np.mean, axis=1).to_numpy())
```